# Using time to change theme with swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to add in a feature that will change the background of that point twice a day.  If it is 6:00 am then the app will show picture 1 and at 6:00 pm the picture will change to 2. If anyone knows how to do this please help.

Comment: How about implementing a `Timer`, which checks every minute the current time and update your UI accordingly?

Comment: @kcpac Why not just schedule a `Timer` to fire once and perform the background change and setup the next `Timer`

Comment: Calculate the difference between now and 6:00. Then setup a timer with that time interval: `Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: <interval>, repeats: false) { ... }`. It can be even a recursive call to setup next timer (for next 6:00).

Comment: if you repeat the job, there is no need to reinitialise a new timer. Of course it makes sense to check, if the UI needs to be updated at all.

Comment: Will the image1 be presented from 6 AM till 6 PM? and vice versa for Image2?

Comment: Yes, image 1 should show from 6am until 5:59pm and image 2 should show from 6pm until 5:59 am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a timer to make the checks more or less frequent, but if you just want to set the image based on the time you could use something like this...

**Swift 3**

```
let hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date())

if hour >= 6 || hour <= 17 {
    print("use image one")
} else {
    print("use image two")
}
```